# How to optimize my website better? (PageSpeed Insights)

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, optimization, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to optimize my website according to the recommendations from PageSpeed Insights. The link of my website is [Evant](https://evantweb.azurewebsites.net/). There are two recommendations that I have problem with; first is to eliminate the render blocking css. I tried to make some of them preload but it turns out the css is not loading properly when I do it, so I decided to leave all of them load synchronously. The second thing is about browser caching. I tried everything I saw online like adding a .htaccess file which I will write down later, but none of them worked.

The file directory structure :
[image: structure]

.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 # Enable expirations
 ExpiresActive On 
 # Default directive
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 # My favicon
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 # Images
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 # CSS
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 # Javascript
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by recommendation? Something like the google lighthouse project?

For having non-blocking CSS, write the CSS of your entry module inline instead of loading it from a bundled file.

For caching the easiest solution are Service-Workers.